# How to mock a MEF ExportFactory<TGeneric> using Moq instances?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, mef

How can I mock a Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) import into an *ExportFactory[IMyType[T]]*, using mocks of *IMyType[T]* (being itself a generic interface)? Or, in general, specify instances to be returned by the ExportFactory, which can't be created with a constructor alone?

Moq can't create a mock instance directly, as far as I know. I want an alternative to implementing the whole interface, which may be much larger and change, while I don't want to change the test.

I once found a very complex ExportProvider code, with key-value strings, which didn't work if the generic type of the *ExportFactory[T]* was itself generic.

**Edit:** 
It turned out that the existing code used contract name strings, generated from type.FullName. This was fine for non-generics, but generics have a different name syntax. The code I worked with, already has a quite complex class, derived from ExportProvider and overriding some original methods, which allows Moq mock.Object instances to be returned by the factory. It's actually always the same instance, not really a factory. See also this question on CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208550/retrieve-generic-contract-names-for-managed-extensibility-framework

```
// actual generic type is meaningless here, but it is a generic interface
public interface IMyType<T>
{
    string GetMessage();
}

public class FactoryImporter<T>
{
    [Import]
    ExportFactory<IMyType<T>> MyTypeFactory {get;set;}
} 

public class Tester
{
    public void TestFactoryImporter()
    {
        Func<IMyType<string>> createMockFunc = () =>
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IMyType<string>>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.GetMessage()).Returns("I'm a mocked IMyType<string>");
            return mock.Object;
        }

        var regBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();

        // pseudo-code, how to do this in reality?
        regBuilder.ForType<IMyType<string>>().CreateInstance(createMockFunc);

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var appCatalog = new ApplicationCatalog(regBuilder);
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(appCatalog);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        var factoryImporter = new FactoryImporter<string>();
        container.ComposeParts(factoryImporter);

        Assert.AreEqual(
            "I'm a mocked IMyType<string>",
            factoryImporter.MyTypeFactory.GetExport().Value.GetMessage());
    }
}
```